# bundle exec rake db:migrate says Run `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

```
bundle install
```

This works perfectly fine. But when I do

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

It says

```
Could not find byebug-6.0.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: Did you tried running `bundle install` again?

Comment: yes, it seems like it's a never ending loop

Comment: Try `gem install byebug` and check.

Comment: 1 gem installed. 

And then shows the same error again. http://imgur.com/E4hQont

Comment: Why are you giving `sudo`? Just run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Because running without sudo I get a lot of warnings followed by :  rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
!

Comment: Try to update bundler first `gem update bundler`. Either with or without sudo depending where it has been installed `gem which bundler`. Old versions are known to have problems with dependency resolution.

Comment: update doess't solve the problem. `gem which bundler` gives /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb .

Comment: did you used `byebug` anywhere in the codebase? Can you share your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

From comments, I saw that you use 2 different types of commands, 1 with `sudo` and 1 without.

Problem is: `sudo` is another user (root user), so what you install by `sudo` may not be applied for other users and vice versa.

The solution I could think of is to use all `sudo` commands, since your current user seems not to have access to PG.

```
sudo bundle install
sudo bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I just troubleshat this same problem. I finally tried removing byebug and was offered a choice of `byebug_6.0.2` or `byebug_8.1.0`. Removing the earlier version didn’t do it so I removed the other as well. I then reinstalled using

`gem install byebug`

That gave me another failed migrate, this time blaming debug_inspector. I ran

`gem install debug_inspector`

After that I was able to run `rake db:migrate` as expected.